# What is the diffrence between django apps and django contenttype?

Tags: python, django

What is the diffrence between django apps and django contenttype in getting models for example

```
from django.apps import apps
model = apps.get_model(app_label=app_label,model_name=model_name)
```

and

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
model = ContentType.objects.get(app_label=app_label, model = model).model_class()
```

Comment: The second will make a query to the database. Whereas the last retains a list of objects for that app, and thus will normally *not* make a roundtrip to the database. This also means that the database can "stay behind" certain model updates, and thus might still contain the "old name" of a model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `apps.get_model(…)` will look for the model stored in the `AppConfig` that corresponds with the `app_name`. Indeed, if we look at the [source code [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/apps/registry.py#L186-L211), we see:

> ```
> def get_model(self, app_label, model_name=None, require_ready=True):
>     # …
>     if require_ready:
>         self.check_models_ready()
>     else:
>         self.check_apps_ready()
>
>     if model_name is None:
>         app_label, model_name = app_label.split('.')
>
>     app_config = self.get_app_config(app_label)
>
>     if not require_ready and app_config.models is None:
>         app_config.import_models()
>
>     return app_config.get_model(model_name, require_ready=require_ready)
> ```

It thus first determines the `AppConfig` that corresponds with the `app_label`, and then makes a call to get the model object. The `AppConfig` has a list where it stores all the models for that `App`. Then the [`get_model(…)` logic of the `AppConfig` is used [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/apps/config.py#L257-L271):

> ```
> def get_model(self, model_name, require_ready=True):
>     # …
>     if require_ready:
>         self.apps.check_models_ready()
>     else:
>         self.apps.check_apps_ready()
>     try:
>         return self.models[model_name.lower()]
>     except KeyError:
>         raise LookupError(
>             "App '%s' doesn't have a '%s' model." % (self.label, model_name))
> ```

It thus will look for a model in the dictionary and return a reference to that model object.

---

If you work with the `ContentType`, you actually first make a database query to fetch the corresponding `ContentType`. You can query the `ContentType` by id for example (which is the main purpose of a content type: mapping a primary key to a model).

Once the `ContentType` is retrieved, Django knows the name of the app and the name of the model. It then will make a call to the `apps.get_model(…)` that we discussed earlier, and thus retrieve a reference to the correct model. Indeed, the [`.model_class()` method is implemented as [GitHub]](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.2.x/django/contrib/contenttypes/models.py#L161-L166):

> ```
> def model_class(self):
>     # …
>     try:
>         return apps.get_model(self.app_label, self.model)
>     except LookupError:
>         return None
> ```

If you thus know the app name and the model name, it makes no sense to work with the `ContentType`. Especially since the database can run behind on the content types, and thus return the wrong one. The `ContentType` model is usually used to refer to a specific model *in the database*. For example by using a [**`GenericForeignKey`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.fields.GenericForeignKey) which consists out of a pair of two fields: one `ForeignKey` that links to an item of the `ContentType`, and one with the primary key of the object referred to. If you access the `GenericForeignKey` of a model object, it will first retrieve the `ContentType` of that object, and then make a query on that model with the primary key of the record object.